# Use redirect url when creating skadnetwork for web ads attributable ad link

Tags: skadnetwork

I would like to use skadnetwork 4.0 new feature of web ads
based on this link from Apple web site: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/skadnetworkforwebads/creating_an_attributable_ad_link
I need to create this type of html link:

```
<a href="https://apps.apple.com/app/id{itunes_item_id}" 
attributionDestination="https://example.com" 
attributionSourceNonce="t8naKxXHTzuTJhNfljADPQ">
</a>
```

My question: is it possible to use at the href a link that will do redirect (client or server(302)) to the app store url in order to receive app-installation attribution from a web ad or I must put a direct link to the app store in order it will work ?